# How can i update my master data extension from another data extensions in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I am having as data extension name as MasterDe and i want to add and update it with the data that is in other data extension named as DataDeA, DataDeB and DataDeC.

All these Dataextension having two field FieldA and FieldB

First I want to add the data from these data-extension into MasterDe then I want to update it when ever there is a change in data in other data-extension.

Is there is any way to implement it using Automations or AMPscript

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted (the checkmark symbol), so others can easily see your problem has been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with an Automation containing SQL query activities. You need to select the fields you like to write/update to/in your MasterDe and make sure you have a matching primary key, so the fields can be updated correctly.

Things you need to consider:

- You need to have the field used as primary key in MasterDe present in your other data extensions.
- You need to use the Update type in your query activities (this adds records that aren't present in the target data extension and updates data of already present records)
- Updating "whenever there is a change" isn't possible unfortunately, as an automation cannot listen to data changes. You can however schedule the automation to run every hour, so if there aren't such frequent and important changes your MasterDe will be more or less up to date.

The Marketing Cloud documentation contains example queries with explanation, that should help you figure out the syntax, etc. if you aren't already familiar with SQL.

Your query for updating MasterDe with data from DataDeA could look similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
    PrimaryKey,
    FieldA,
    FieldB
FROM
    DataDeA
```

You'd have "MasterDe" selected as target data extension of your query activity and "Update" as data action.

**Related documentation:**

- [SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)
- [Use the SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5)
- [SQL Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Markus !